# Upgrading elastic client and dependencies for connecting to older elastic server instance

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm currently using following Elastic client libraries in my spring boot application:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.3</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

And following code in config class:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;

@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.x.y.repository",queryLookupStrategy= Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND)
...
public class AppConfiguration extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
...
 @Bean
    public Client client() {
...
final Settings elasticsearchSettings = Settings.builder().put("http.enabled", "false")/*.put("index.mapping.single_type","false")*/
                    .put("cluster.name", elasticSearchCluster).build();
            logr.debug("elasticSearchCluster--> %d", elasticSearchCluster);
            logr.debug("elasticSearchHost --> %d", elasticSearchHost);
            try {
                TransportClient client1 = new PreBuiltTransportClient(elasticsearchSettings);
                client1.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
                // return client;
                setClient(client1);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                logr.error("Not able to connect to Elastic Search: ", e);
            }
        }
        return client;
    }
...
```

Above app connects to ES 5.5.3 server fine. I'd now like to use the latest 7.6.0 version of client dependencies and rest client.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use latest version client to connect to older versions of elastic search server instance?
2. If so, can you pls share the library versions I should use to make this work correctly? Some versions I tried threw errors around lucene query parsers; Others compiled but threw errors when running.

Answer (score 0):

No. This won't work. This is no problem specific to Spring Data Elasticsearch, but comes from the evolution of the elasticsearch libraries themselves.

Between Elasticsearch 5 and 7 the format of the queries and the format of the returned data changed, so a 7.6.1 client cannot understand responses from a 5.5.3 server and the same for queries in the other direction.

So you will need to migrate your ES cluster from 5.5.3 to a current version before adapting to the actual Spring Data Elasticsearch.